# Calculating a Permutation with Repetitions of Lexigraphic

Tags: performance, algorithm, permutation, combinatorics, factorial

I have a question concerning combinatorics, specifically permutations and lexigraphic indexing. I have calculated a permutation of a set given a lexigraphic index in the past, but these were permutations ***without*** repetition.

Now I would like to calculate the permutation of given lexigraphic index ***with*** repetitions. My problem is I don't know how to approach the lexigraphic indexing of permutations with repetition.

Suppose I have the following set of elements" `{A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H}`

I would like to calculate the permutation of 20 of these elements with lexigraphic index of `n`; `n` being 64 bit number. How do I determine the lexigraphic indexing? Can I still use a factorial base approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose you have 8 elements (like in your example), which means you need 3 bits for index. To define permutation of length 20 you need `3*20=60` bits.

So integer values `v` from `[0,2^60)` will define all permutations with repeats, where `v & 7` will be the index of first item in the permutation, `(v & (7 << 3) >> 3)` - index on the second element, and so forth ...

Answer (score 0):

the size of your set is 8 and your length is 20, so totally there r 8^20 permutations. if u want to calculate the nth permutation, u can simple determine bit by bit. ie the 1st bit is 'A' if n is smaller than 7^20, 'B' if n is in the range [7^20, 2*7^20) etc.